# Background images rendering problems on wp7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, background, rendering

In my WP7 app i'm having problems with background images rendering badly. It looks like the images are rendered using 8-bit colors, and in general looks ugly. They're .png. Heres a screenshot of how it looks in the app:
 [screenshot](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg39/scaled.php?server=39&filename=captureejj.png&res=landing)

Does anyone know what causes this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Does this happen with every image you use? Did you try it in a device? I did not face an issue like this so far for all my apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to enabled 32bit colour?

To do this, open up your WMAppManifest.xml and in the App element add BitsPerPixel="32"

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App BitsPerPixel="32" xmlns="" ProductID="{25aef417-
```

Not sure if this will resolve the issue, but the fact your using a .png image and only having 16bit colour could be related.

Comment: Adding BitsPerPixel="32" in WMPAppManifest did the trick! Thanks alot.

Comment: Good, Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT "enable 32 bit color". Many devices have only 16 bit LCD, so they'll still have the issues - you'll just not know about them.

If you really need smooth gradients, use predithered backgrounds, eg. http://nerdplusart.com/photoshop-action-for-windows-phone-7-dithering However it's still not flowing with the of Windows Phone.

The true solution is to change your design to solid, primary colors. This is the choice user have made buying WP device and you should respect it.

Comment: Did you look at the screen shot, or the fact that the answer above was marked as solving the OP's issue? From the screen shot, it doesn't seem like dithering was the issue there.

Comment: @AndrewBarber It "solved" the issue on SOME phones but it remained on other models. I just wanted to add a warning that enabling 32bit color is not a "magic-fix-all". So your app remains broken for many users. Dithering is not an issue here - it's the lack of it, so it has to be introduced via predithering. I have lumia 800(oled) and 710(lcd) on my desk: believe me, predithering solves all problems with too similar colors.

Comment: I understand what you are saying; My point was that I don't think dithering (or lack of it) was the particular problem with the particular image here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber : So what do you think it is? I think he tried to add an unobtrusive background. But bleak image has exactly same problem as gradient: pixels of *nearly* same color are lying next to each other. (Which conversion to low-res colorspace groups into uniform spots.)